# Select row with group by and max in JPQL

Tags: sql, jpql

I have below structure. Not in one table but just to keep it simple:

```
Press       | Batch        | Start time
-------------------------------------------------
PRESS_1     | 2051         | 2017-05-18T00:00:00
PRESS_1     | 2052         | 2017-05-19T00:00:00
PRESS_2     | 2053         | 2017-05-20T00:00:00
PRESS_2     | 2054         | 2017-05-16T00:00:00
PRESS_3     | 2055         | 2017-05-12T00:00:00
PRESS_3     | 2056         | 2017-05-18T00:00:00
PRESS_3     | 2057         | 2017-05-19T00:00:00
```

I want to get the last planned batch for each press. The result should be:

```
Press       | Batch        | Start time
-------------------------------------------------
PRESS_1     | 2052         | 2017-05-19T00:00:00
PRESS_2     | 2053         | 2017-05-20T00:00:00
PRESS_3     | 2057         | 2017-05-19T00:00:00
```

However, when I group by press and also want to select the batch. I am obliged to put the batch into the 'Group By' clause.

```
Select x.Press, x.Batch, max(x.StartTime)
From myTable x
Group by x.Press
```

How can this be achieved using JPQL?

Comment: @Veljko89 as you can see for PRESS_2 this is not always the case.

Comment: This question has been answered numerous times here in SO. Please try to do some research before posting a question.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos It was quite hard to find the right words to google this. But please keep the post open as this considers JPQL which is very much more limited than the duplicate post you refer to. Also that particular case is not the same principle.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Please check. I have edited the question.

Comment: I think you also mentioned about a SQL solution in the original version of your post. Never mind, I will vote for re-opening the question.

Answer (score 5):

as you want to select entry with max start_time of each press, you use something as mentioned below as well -

```
Select x.Press, x.Batch, x.StartTime
From x 
where (press,starttime) in 
(select press, max(starttime) 
from x group by press)
```

lets give a try and please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you could use an inner join with the aggregated  result for grouping

```
select * from my_table as t1
inner join  (
select Press, max(start_time) my_time
from my_table 
group by Press ) t2 on t1.Press = T2.Press and t2.my_time = t1.start_time
```

or avoiding join

```
select * from my_table as t1
where (t1.Press, t1.start_time) in (
select Press, max(start_time) 
from my_table 
group by Press )
```

OR if you ORM is limited you could create a proper view and then use the view name as a table avoiding the subquery

Comment: Unfortunately, using subqueries in the join class is not allowed in JPQL

Comment: is allowed the use of tuple ..?  anyway answer updated  with tuple

Comment: appearently also no tupples :( It is very limited because it's not native.

Comment: the batch number is concorde with the start_time?  .. almost in the same press?

Comment: I have update the answer adding a simple suggestion if you ORM framework is limitated ..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just get the max from the batch as well assuming that you batch increases with each start time:

```
Select x.Press, max(x.Batch), max(x.StartTime)
From x
Group by x.Press
```

Comment: This will not work. For press 2 it will return: PRESS_2, 2054, 2017-05-20. So the batch is not correct.